# Visual basic .net write to xml

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to write following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ns2:IntraConsignment IntraListingsNbr="1" xmlns:ns2="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/IntraConsignment" xmlns="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/InputCommon">
```

Is it possible to achieve this in visual basic using xmlwriter?

I'm only struggling with the two first lines. The complete example looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>     
<ns2:IntraConsignment xmlns="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/InputCommon" xmlns:ns2="http://www.minfin.fgov.be/IntraConsignment" IntraListingsNbr="1">
    <ns2:Representative>
        <RepresentativeID identificationType="NVAT" issuedBy="BE">0000000097</RepresentativeID>
        <Name>TEST Gevolmachtigde Manadataire NV SA</Name>
        <Street>AV Test-laan 8</Street>
        <PostCode>9999</PostCode>
        <City>TESTCITY</City>
        <CountryCode>BE</CountryCode>
        <EmailAddress>scsdferfzefc@dsfsdf.be</EmailAddress>
        <Phone>0212487645648</Phone>
    </ns2:Representative>
    <ns2:RepresentativeReference>CCFFLot2 LK</ns2:RepresentativeReference>
    <ns2:IntraListing AmountSum="1000.00" DeclarantReference="" ClientsNbr="1" SequenceNumber="1">
        <ns2:Declarant>
            <VATNumber>0000000097</VATNumber>
            <Name>BELGIUM nv sa</Name>
            <Street>AV. testLAAN 20</Street>
            <PostCode>9999</PostCode>
            <City>TESTCITY</City>
            <CountryCode>BE</CountryCode>
            <EmailAddress>scsdferfzefc@dsfsdf.be</EmailAddress>
            <Phone>0212487645648</Phone>
        </ns2:Declarant>
        <ns2:Period>
            <ns2:Month>11</ns2:Month>
            <ns2:Year>2011</ns2:Year>
        </ns2:Period>
        <ns2:IntraClient SequenceNumber="1">
            <ns2:CompanyVATNumber issuedBy="IT">00399999991</ns2:CompanyVATNumber>
            <ns2:Code>L</ns2:Code>
            <ns2:Amount>1000.00</ns2:Amount>
            <ns2:CorrectingPeriod>
                <ns2:Month>11</ns2:Month>
                <ns2:Year>2010</ns2:Year>
            </ns2:CorrectingPeriod>
        </ns2:IntraClient>
        <ns2:Comment>free text max 2000 characters</ns2:Comment>
    </ns2:IntraListing>
</ns2:IntraConsignment>
```

Comment: That exact string?  I only ask because technically that's not well formed XML.  The document element doesn't have an ending tag.

Comment: I added the complete example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use an `XmlWriter` to generate an XML document which has those top-level nodes.  Here's an example:

```vb
Dim settings As New XmlWriterSettings()
settings.Indent = True
settings.IndentChars = vbTab
settings.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")
Using writer As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("test.xml", settings)
    writer.WriteStartDocument()
    writer.WriteStartElement("ns2", "IntraConsignment", "http://www.minfin.fgov.be/IntraConsignment")
    writer.WriteAttributeString("IntraListingsNbr", "1")
    writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "http://www.minfin.fgov.be/InputCommon")
    ' ...
    writer.WriteEndElement()
    writer.WriteEndDocument()
End Using
```

Since you didn't specify which particular part of the task you were having trouble with, I can't adequately elaborate on the part that confuses you, but if you want to ask about any part of it specifically, I'd be happy to add more explanation.

Comment: Can the encoding be changed to ISO-8859-1?
Or is this not relevant for the xml?

Comment: Sorry, I noticed that mistake in my example immediately upon posting it and already updated it before you even asked :)

Comment: Wow.  You learn something every day.  I don't use `XmlWriter` much, so I had no idea that Microsoft now recommends using `XmlWriter.Create` instead of `XmlTextWriter`.  Apparently that's been the case since .NET 2.0.  I'm going to have to change my SO example ways :)  Anyway, yes, I updated my example to show you how that can be done.

Comment: Thanks Steven, that's great work.
In the meantime I also found a solution.
One other thing, does the order of the namespace/schemas matters?

Comment: No.  Provided the consuming application uses a correctly-implemented XML parser to read the document, that should never matter.